# Set NSUserDefault with timestamp from a timepicker

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

I´m trying to get the value from a date picker, convert it to a timeStamp and then set a `NSUserDefaults` with the timestamp value. But I get multiple error messages.

> 1: Implicit conversation of time_t (aka long) to id_Nullable is disallowed with ARC
>
> 2: incompatible integer to pointer conversation sending time_t (aka long) to parameter of type _id Nullable is disallowed with ARC

```
- (IBAction)createActivityButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    time_t dateStart = (time_t) [self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];
    [defaults setObject:dateStart forKey:@"TimeStartString"];
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `time_t`? `timeIntervalSince1970` returns `NSTimeInterval`, not `time_t`.

Answer (score 3):

`setObject:` of `NSUserDefaults` expects an object (pointer) rather than a scalar type like `time_t`.

Why not saving the `NSTimeInterval` aka `double` directly:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSTimeInterval dateStart = [self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];
[defaults setDouble:dateStart forKey:@"TimeStartString"];
```

or – as rmaddy pointed out in the comment – still simpler

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.datePicker.date forKey:@"TimeStartDate"];
```

Comment: Of course another options is to simply store `self.datePicker.date`.

Comment: Thanks it works! :) I noticed one issue that creates problem. Sometimes the date picker saves a number with decimals. Like 1457100262,9323. Is it a way to make sure the number saved is only full numbers?